# How to access specific custom attribute elements with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm still trying to understand the syntax for BeautifulSoup and hope someone can put this right.

I've got an article - https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-49345912

I want to do some NLP on the body text.

I worked out some script which gets to the point to an extent - thanks to https://towardsdatascience.com/super-simple-way-to-scrape-bbc-news-articles-in-python-5fe1e6ee82d9

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

class BBC:
    def __init__(self, url:str):
        article = requests.get(url)
        self.soup = bs(article.content, "html.parser")
        self.body = self.get_body()
        self.title = self.get_title()
        
    def get_body(self) -> list:
        body = self.soup.find("article")
        return [p.text for p in body.find_all("p", class_="ssrcss-1q0x1qg-Paragraph eq5iqo00")]
    
    def get_title(self) -> str:
        return self.soup.find("h1").text

print(BBC("https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-49345912").body)
print(BBC("https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-49345912").title)
```

So far so groovy.
But say I want to filter on something like div blocks that have the attribute 'data-component="text-block"' and then filter out the p tags within them. At this point I'm lost. How do I identify a custom 'data-component' attribute?
Here's an example.

```
<div data-component="text-block" class="ssrcss-11r1m41-RichTextComponentWrapper ep2nwvo0"><div class="ssrcss-7uxr49-RichTextContainer e5tfeyi1"><p class="ssrcss-1q0x1qg-Paragraph eq5iqo00">"This is a big symbolic moment," he said. "Climate change doesn't have a beginning or end and I think the philosophy behind this plaque is to place this warning sign to remind ourselves that historical events are happening, and we should not normalise them. We should put our feet down and say, okay, this is gone, this is significant."</p></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as hard as I thought: I just added a new function to my class:

```
def body_search(self) -> list:
        text_blocks = self.soup.find_all('div', {'data-component': 'text-block'})
        result = []
        for text_block in text_blocks:
            paragraphs = text_block.find_all('p')
            for p in paragraphs:
                result.append(p.get_text())
        return result
```